# Topic subject misedited

Tags: support, title

I started a topic and gave it a subject. Someone changed the subject. The subject is now seriously irrelevant, impeding other users' searches for the answer I wanted and leading to question duplication, and, besides, the subject is a question to which I already know the answer (which is "no") and the answer on the page does not address it.

Could someone please edit the subject or tell me how to do it myself (I didn't see this in Help)? I'll assume the old subject was problematic, so the proposed subjects are different (either of these will be fine):

> if relationship said to be not a contract
>
> if relationship that may be a contract is said to be not a contract

This is the question: *[Can a business disclaim a contract of adhesion?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/28941/can-a-business-disclaim-a-contract-of-adhesion)*

Thank you.

Comment: It may be better to direct questions like this to the specific site's meta. https://law.meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @apaul not really, this can be considered as a generic question: "how you change a title that was wrongly edited". Voting to reopen.

Comment: BTW, you didn't "start a topic" you "asked a question." You didn't give it a subject, you gave it a title. Knowing the terminology will make it easier for you to learn how the sites work.

Comment: Besides being for my original question, it was generic across all sites, since Help did not address it. I didn't know that each site has its own meta or I would have searched that, but Help would be a good place for the instruction. Thanks also for the terminology.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: That, at the URL, says nothing about editing a title and the title being editable with the question is not intuitive. Should that help page be edited to explicitly include editing the title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the "edit" link below the question.

You get the edit view, with the title (or subject) in a single line text box towards the top of the page and the body in a multi-line text box below:

[image]

Just edit the title in the same way as you would edit the body of the question.

If you're not happy with the whole edit you can also "rollback" the edit by clicking on the "edited" link and getting the revisions page:

https://law.stackexchange.com/posts/28941/revisions

If you're the post author or have full edit privilege on the site, there'll be a "rollback" link against each revision (apart from the latest)